# React Hooks Todo App 'TypeError: Object(...) is not a function' error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm developing a Todo App with React Hooks. I get the error **"TypeError: Object (...) is not a function"** when defining the functional component.

React version: 16.7.0

Here is the error:

```
  1 | import React, { useState } from "react"
  2 | import "./App.css"
  3 | 
> 4 | export default function TodoApp() {
  5 |   const [todo, setTodo] = useState("")
  6 |   const [todos, setTodos] = useState([])
  7 |
```

And my code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import "./App.css"

export default function TodoApp() {
  const [todo, setTodo] = useState("")
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([])

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setTodo(e.target.value)
  }

  const addTodo = () => {
    setTodos([
      ...todos,
      {
        id: todos.length + 1,
        title: todo,
        isDone: false
      }
    ])
  }

  continued...
```

Comment: Hooks were not introduced until [React 16.8](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html). If you are really on 16.7 this could be the problem.

Comment: yeah solved, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a mistake inside the `addTodo` function. If your current state depends on the previous state you have to pass a function instead to `setTodos` to avoid bugs. Try this:

```
const addTodo = () => {
    setTodos(prevTodos => [
      ...prevTodos,
      {
        id: prevTodos.length + 1,
        title: todo,
        isDone: false
      }
    ])
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer mate. React version is out of date. The problem was solved when I updated it.